# Relationships (Foreign Keys) in mySQL

Tags: mysql, foreign-key-relationship

I'm very much a beginner in mySQL as a whole, but I'm having a particular amount of trouble visualising/understanding foreign keys and relationships in mySQL.

The database I'm playing around with is based on a college. There are tables for information about Students, Staff, Courses, Register, Rooms, and Campuses. Ultimately, what I want to do is create a view that will allow me to see what students were absent from what courses, but in order to do that, I think that I first need to create a temporary table joining the Student table and Register table together. In this temporary table, I'll have the student's name, course name, and Register info absent, present, etc.).

My instructor tells me that because relationships flow both ways, and can be accessed through relationships to other tables, I need to be wary about adding too many foreign keys into the mix. Here is my current table structure:

Tables:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `campus` (
  `CampusID` int(8) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `CampusName` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `CampusCourses` int(8) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`CampusID`),
  KEY `CampusCourses` (`CampusCourses`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COMMENT='Holds attributes relating to the campuses within the college' AUTO_INCREMENT=8 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `course` (
  `CourseID` int(8) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `CourseName` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `CourseType` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`CourseID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COMMENT='Holds attributes relating to the courses offered by the college' AUTO_INCREMENT=21 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `register` (
  `RegisterID` int(8) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `RegisterType` enum('Present','Absent','Late','Reason','Left Early') NOT NULL,
  `RoomLocation` int(8) NOT NULL,
  `CourseAssociated` int(8) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`RegisterID`),
  KEY `CourseAssociated` (`CourseAssociated`),
  KEY `RoomLocation` (`RoomLocation`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COMMENT='Holds attributes relating to the Student Register' AUTO_INCREMENT=10 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `room` (
  `RoomID` int(8) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `RoomType` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `RoomNumber` varchar(6) NOT NULL,
  `RegisterValue` int(8) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`RoomID`),
  KEY `RegisterValue` (`RegisterValue`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COMMENT='Holds attributes relating to the rooms available at the college' AUTO_INCREMENT=23 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `staff` (
  `StaffID` int(8) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `StaffFirstName` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `StaffLastName` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `StaffGender` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `StaffPhone` varchar(11) NOT NULL,
  `StaffAddress` varchar(510) NOT NULL,
  `CourseTaught` int(8) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`StaffID`),
  KEY `CourseTaught` (`CourseTaught`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COMMENT='Holds attributes relating to staff members at the college' AUTO_INCREMENT=30 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `student` (
  `StudentID` int(8) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `StudentFirstName` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `StudentLastName` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `StudentGender` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `StudentPhone` varchar(11) NOT NULL,
  `StudentAddress` varchar(510) NOT NULL,
  `CourseTaken` int(8) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`StudentID`),
  KEY `CourseTaken` (`CourseTaken`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COMMENT='Holds attributes relating to students at the college' AUTO_INCREMENT=21 ;
```

Constraints:

```
ALTER TABLE `campus`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `campus_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`CampusCourses`) REFERENCES `course` (`CourseID`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE CASCADE;

ALTER TABLE `register`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `register_course_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`CourseAssociated`) REFERENCES `course` (`CourseID`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `register_room_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`RoomLocation`) REFERENCES `room` (`RoomID`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE CASCADE;

ALTER TABLE `room`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `room_register_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`RegisterValue`) REFERENCES `register` (`RegisterID`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE CASCADE;

ALTER TABLE `staff`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `staff_course_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`CourseTaught`) REFERENCES `course` (`CourseID`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE CASCADE;

ALTER TABLE `student`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `student_course_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`CourseTaken`) REFERENCES `course` (`CourseID`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

My question is, how can I build a temporary table which gathers together columns from `student.FirstName, student.LastName, course.CourseName, register.RegisterType`, and build a view around that? I feel that I'm missing some foreign keys to build relationships between tables, but my instructor tells me otherwise.

Thanks for any help or hints you can offer.

Comment: What does "relationships flow both ways" mean? I cannot make sense of it unless "relationship" is taken as "relation" or "association" as in what a table represents, but you are also using "relationship" for "foreign key".

Answer (score 0):

A foreign key from a table & column list to a referenced table and column list says that subrows of values in the first table per its list appear as subrows of values in the second table per its list. Where that is so, tell the DBMS about the foreign key. Although if you declare foreign keys T1 L1 referencing T2 L2 and T2 L2 referencing T3 L3 then you don't need to declare the foreign key that must exist from T1 to T3 because the DBMS enforcing the first two enforces the last.

Foreign keys are constraints. They tell the DBMS that certain database states can't arise. They are irrelevant to querying.

A table holds rows that make some predicate (statement template parameterized by column names) true. The join of tables holds rows that make the AND of the tables' predicates true. A WHERE *condition* restriction of a table holds the rows that make the table's predicate ANDed with the *condition* true. To query, find the predicate for which you want the satisfying rows and write the corresponding relational expression.

I suspect that "adding too many foreign keys into the mix" is your attempt to say "choosing predicates parameterized by columns that don't belong". Eg in your design according to your column and candidate key declarations an instructor teaches exactly one course. If that's not what you want then your column and/or candidate key declarations do not reflect your predicates and/or your predicates are unable to express the situations that can arise. Eg for teaching of zero or more courses: your declared candidate key StaffID cannot be correct for the given columns and if you want StaffID to be the candidate key (which is the better design) then CourseTaught must be dropped from the staff table and you must have another table with StaffID & CourseTaught. Schema design involves finding sufficient non-redundant predicates/tables to describe any situation. (We then *normalize* to simplify the design.)